# How to choose specific Strings from multiple Strings in C Language

Tags: c, string, swap

I have four strings. The user have a choice to swap strings between them. But when I started creating the function, I can't find a way to avoid multiple if statements to cover all the situations. So, I google it, looked on forums but I didn't find out if there is possible in C language to have four variables that somehow each one is linked to a string and then swapping the string between them using the variables. Or is there another way ?

```
char string_one[]  = {"This is string 1"};
char string_two[]  = {"This is string 2"};
char string_three[]= {"This is string 3"};
char string_four []= {"This is string 4"};

void swap_strings(char *str1, char *str2){
//function to swap any 2 strings
  char *temp;
  temp=str1;
  str1=str2;
  str2=temp;
}

void swap_menu(){

  int choice1, choice2;

  printf("Which string do you want to swap: ");
  scanf("%i", &choice1);

  printf("Enter string o you want to swap with: ");
  scanf("%i", &choice2);

  if(choice1 == 1 && choice2 == 2)
    swap_strings(string_one, string_two );

  if(choice1 == 2 && choice2 == 3)
    swap_strings(string_two, string_three );


 if(choice1 == 3 && choice2 == 4)
    swap_strings(string_three, string_four );
  
  if(choice1 == 1 && choice2 == 3)
    swap_strings(string_one, string_three );

}
```

Comment: Maybe with a for loop.  Starting from zero, going four times and with an inner for loop again four times

Comment: If you assigned the strings contiguous positions in memory by using an array of strings, you could generalize the series of `if`s; _eg_ `const char *strings[] = { "a", "b", "c" };`.

Comment: Your `swap_strings` function doesn't do anything, since you're modifying two pointers. In general, if you have some number of things and want to access them by index, then use an array rather than a lot of variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to index the strings (as you do here) you can use an array of strings, rather than 4 array variables.

To swap two of the strings, you need to modify the actual pointers rather than copies of them as you do in your code.

Here's a modified, working version of your code. It even includes some basic error-checking, and prints out the strings before and after.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *strings[] = {
  "This is string 1",
  "This is string 2",
  "This is string 3",
  "This is string 4",
};

void swap_strings(const char **str1, const char **str2){
  const char *temp;
  temp = *str1;
  *str1 = *str2;
  *str2 = temp;
}

void swap_menu(){
  int choice1, choice2;
  printf("Which string do you want to swap: ");
  scanf("%i", &choice1);

  printf("Enter string do you want to swap with: ");
  scanf("%i", &choice2);

  if (choice1 < 1 || choice2 < 1 || choice1 > 4 || choice2 > 4) {
    printf("choices (%d, %d) are out of range\n", choice1, choice2);
    return;
  }
  swap_strings(&strings[choice1-1], &strings[choice2-1]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", i+1, strings[i]);
  }
  swap_menu();
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", i+1, strings[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also important to check the return value of `scanf` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: To improve the user experience, where a user accidentally enters the same number twice but thinks he didn't and is surprised by the unchanging output, you might want to check for that condition and alert the user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *string_one  = "This is string 1";
char *string_two  = "This is string 2";
char *string_three= "This is string 3";
char *string_four = "This is string 4";

void
swap_strings(char **str1, char **str2)
{
    char *temp = *str1;;
    *str1 = *str2;
    *str2 = temp;
}

void
swap_menu(void)
{
    char **d[] = { &string_one, &string_two, &string_three, &string_four };
    int c[2];
    printf("Which string do you want to swap: ");
    if( scanf("%i", c) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( c[0] < 1 || c[0] > 4 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid entry\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Enter string you want to swap with: ");
    if( scanf("%i", c + 1) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( c[1] < 1 || c[1] > 4 || c[0] == c[1] ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid entry\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    swap_strings(d[c[0] - 1], d[c[1] - 1]);
}

int
main(void)
{
    swap_menu();
    printf("%s\n", string_one);
    printf("%s\n", string_two);
    printf("%s\n", string_three);
    printf("%s\n", string_four);
    return 0;
}
```